# regexp match group with the exception of a member of the group

Tags: ruby, regex

So, there are a number of regular expression which matches a particular group like the following:

```
/./ - Any character except a newline.
/./m - Any character (the m modifier enables multiline mode)
/\w/ - A word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_])
/\s/ - Any whitespace character
```

And in ruby:

```
/[[:punct:]]/ - Punctuation character
/[[:space:]]/ - Whitespace character ([:blank:], newline, carriage return, etc.)
/[[:upper:]]/ - Uppercase alphabetical
```

So, here is my question: how do I get a regexp to match a group like this, but exempt a character out?

Examples:

- match all punctuations apart from the question mark
- match all whitespace characters apart from the new line
- match all words apart from "go"... etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use character class subtraction.

[Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-ruby.html):

> The syntax `[…&&[…]]` allows you to use a logical AND on several character classes to ensure that a character is present in them all. Intersecting with a negated character, as ***in `[…&&[^…]]` allows you to subtract that class from the original class***.

Consider [this code](http://ideone.com/xYj7Lq):

```
s = "./?!"
res = s.scan(/[[:punct:]&&[^!]]/)
puts res
```

Output is only `.`, `/` and `?` since `!` is excluded.

Restricting with a lookahead (as sawa has written just now) is also possible, but is not required when you have this subtraction supported. When you need to restrict some longer values (more than 1 character) a lookahead is required.
In many cases, a lookahead must be anchored to a word boundary to return correct results. As an example of using a lookahead to restrict punctuation (single character matching generic pattern):

```
/(?:(?!!)[[:punct:]])+/
```

This will match 1 or more punctuation symbols but a `!`.

The `puts "./?!".scan(/(?:(?!!)[[:punct:]])+/)` code will output `./?` (see [demo](http://ideone.com/jaUFtO))

**Use character class subtraction whenever you need to restrict with *single* characters**, it is more efficient than using lookaheads.

So, the 3rd scenario regex must look like:

```
/\b(?!go\b)\w+\b/
        ^^
```

If you write `/(?!\bgo\b)\b\w+\b/`, the regex engine will check each position in the input string. If you use a `\b` at the beginning, only word boundary positions will be checked, and the pattern will yield better performance. Also note that the ^^ `\b` is very important since it makes the regex engine check for the *whole word `go`*. If you remove it, it will only restrict to the words that *do not start with `go`*.

Comment: Your solution works for single character matches, but does not extend to "match all words apart from "go"... etc".

Comment: I know, I have not finished when you posted your answer. I am not a computer and cannot type the whole answer in just a minute. Besides, **just a lookahead** might not be enough.

Comment: I finished. My wife says we run out of bread, and I can't solve that with regexps :)

Answer (score 3):

Put what you want to exclude inside a negative lookahead in front of the match. For example,

- To match all punctuations apart from the question mark,

  ```
  /(?!\?)[[:punct:]]/
  ```
- To match all words apart from `"go"`,

  ```
  /(?!\bgo\b)\b\w+\b/
  ```

Comment: Output of `("?.,".match /(?!\?)[[:punct:]]/).to_a` is `["."]` - from the other answer I could get output of `[".,"]` - is this working fine?

Comment: You need to use grouping with this approach and match more than 1 character. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: @SunnyK: `match` only fetches the first match, `scan` will fetch all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general approach that is sometimes useful:

```
a = []
".?!,:;-".scan(/[[:punct:]]/) { |s| a << s unless s == '?' }
a #=> [".", "!", ",", ":", ";", "-"]
```

The content of the block is limited only by your imagination.