# How to match a single character with multiple conditions in regex(regular expression) in linux grep?

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, match

The scenario is using linux 'grep' regular expression to match.

I know I can use '[a-z]' to match a single character from range 'a-z' in regex
I also know I can use '[^t]' to match a single character that would not be a literal 't'

Now I want to match a single character that will be picked up from 2 conditions for example, using '[a-z]' and '[^t]' at the same time.

I already found a way to solve this, which is using '[a-su-z]'.

However, when we have more and more conditions, for example, '[a-z0-9]', '[^t]', '[^h]', '[^e]', '[^145]', how to utilize those conditions at the same time?

To be practical, I need to match 'Exception' in a log file
but there are too many exception,
I know some certain Exception that I do not want to match, for example, pattern like '[^t]Exception', [^n]Exception', etc...

so how can I match a single character with multiple conditions in one regex expression?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Notice that I am able to use [abcdfghz14389] to specify a set of possibilities, but I just want to avoid this way, I want to combine multiple conditions to match one single characters in a single regex, thanks!

Comment: Use a lookahead - `(?![the145])[a-z0-9]`. In Java, .NET, Ruby, you may use character class subtraction. I linked to the Java example. Here is one [for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691347/3832970), but the negative lookahead solution is quite enough, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining :D I tried lookahead in java, it worked like a charm. However, I think I was not asking properly, I should've mentioned the regex is used in linux grep scenario, now I already found a solution. Please don't make it duplicate so I can give an answer below, thanks!

Comment: Vote to reopening since OP proposes they have a viable answer for the unique scenario